# How to highlight text following keydown event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to highlight all text following a `#` character in my search form.

I would like to achieve an effect where the text is highlighted until the spacebar is pressed.

```
// Detects hashtag keypress and highlights word
$('#nav-search').on('keydown',function(e){

  // console.log(e.which)
  // 163 == '#'

  if(e.which==163){
    console.log('# Pressed')
  }

});
```

I'm using the `keydown` event to detect the `#` symbol as the input.

An example effect is shown below using bold as the highlight.

e.g. "This is a **#test** **#search** query"

Comment: What is `#nav-search`? Inputs can't have both bold and non-bold text without using a workaround.

Comment: It's an input field.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `replace` for this. Add this to your `keydown` handler:

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/(?!<strong>)(#.*?)\s/g, "<strong>$1</strong>"));
```

The regex matches and captures a hashtag (or octothorp), as well as all non-whitespace characters following it, and then it encloses them in `<strong>` tags.

Comment: Wouldn't it add an extra pair of tags with every keydown event?

Comment: Whoops, yes @NinaLisitsinskaya.

Comment: Thanks. So yes, it would need to encapsulate on whitespace not a following '#'

Comment: This replaces the text with HTML properly, but more importantly, what is `#nav-search`? `<input>` values can't have HTML in them. Or at least, it won't render as HTML.

Comment: Yes, it's input. The overall effect I am after is for anything following a '#' will be placed in a Bootstrap Pill. I was trying to start this by just highlighting the text.

Comment: I would say you'd be better off asking about your desired result and showing an attempt at solving it. Otherwise you're asking us to do frivolous pursuits like embolding input text, which isn't possible without some tedious workarounds. Wouldn't want people to spend time doing that as an answer to your question, only to find out it isn't at all necessary towards your end-goal.